# Please explain the output of the following pointer operation

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, output

I have been trying to figure out how to arrive at the output of the following program.I would basically like to know the status of the character array after each iteration. Would be of great help.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
 char *name="ThE bESt meN wIN";
 for(int i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
  if(islower(name[i]))
     name[i]=toupper(name[i]);
  else
  if(isupper(name[i]))
  {
   if(i%2==0)
    name[i]--;
   else
    name[i]=tolower(name[i-1]);
  }
  }
  cout<<name;
 getch();
}
```

The output is:
SHD BbRT MEe WHh

Comment: Off topic. You are using a quarter century old compiler. Expect some bumps when you transport your knowledge to other applications.

Comment: You are writing to a pointer that points to immutable memory

Comment: The behaviour of the code is undefined.   So no explanation will suffice.

Comment: @LWimsey That's one of the bumps OP is going to have to face.

Comment: Turbo C++ shipped with td32, an excellent debugger. You can use it to step through the program line by line and watch what happens.

Comment: i want to know how the step by step behaviour inside the array as the loop advances

Comment: @BhargabKakati It seems like code from a puzzle. Writing the string on a piece of paper, 'manually' going through the loop and writing down the result is doable

Comment: @LWimsey i have been trying to do exactly that but lost it in the middle

Comment: Please do .Its a request from a learner.Will remember u for this . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `main` return type to `int` and modify this line to let it point to an array of characters that can be modified:

```
char name[]="ThE bESt meN wIN";
```

Then take it step by step, here is the output for each of the 16 iterations. Numbers refer to the actual array index. That should be helpful.

Maybe this is easier to handle, if not use the history

```
initial
ThE bESt meN wIN


0123456789012345
ShE bESt meN wIN  0: T -> S

0123456789012345
SHE bESt meN wIN  1: h -> H

0123456789012345
SHD bESt meN wIN  2: E -> D

0123456789012345
SHD bESt meN wIN  3: space

0123456789012345
SHD BESt meN wIN  4: b -> B

0123456789012345
SHD BbSt meN wIN  5: E -> b

0123456789012345
SHD BbRt meN wIN  6: S -> R

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT meN wIN  7: t -> T

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT meN wIN  8: space

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MeN wIN  9: m -> M

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEN wIN  10: e -> E

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEe wIN  11: N -> e

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEe wIN  12: space

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEe WIN  13: w -> W

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEe WHN  14: I -> H

0123456789012345
SHD BbRT MEe WHh  15: N -> h
```

Comment: Thanks. in the first iteration i=0 how does T change to S ?

Comment: Got it now..Thank You very much. LWimsey